# How to populate json array in spinner

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

How to populate response in spinner.

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<SelectStoresModelResponse>> call, Response<List<SelectStoresModelResponse>> response) {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
            List<SelectStoresModelResponse> basicResponse = response.body();
    }
}
```

My spinner is

```
@Bind(R.id.spnselectstorevw)
    Spinner SelectStores;
```

My json data is:

```
[
    {
     "_id":"656456565646546542",
     "storealias:""abc"
    }
]
```

I want "storealias" in my spinner. Please tell me how to populate storealias in my spinner SelectStores.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Spinner spinner;
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1) ;
java.util.ArrayList<String> strings = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

Prase JSON

```
try {
     JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);

     //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
     JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("Employee");

     //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
     for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


        String name = jsonObject.optString("storealias").toString();

        strings.add(name) ; 

     }
     output.setText(data);
  } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Set data in Sppiner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strings);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Let

```
String response =  {
     "_id":"656456565646546542",
     "storealias:""abc"
    }

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(response);
jsonObject.get("storealias");             // will return abc
```

Comment: What is employee here??